# Let p1, p2 and p3 be the vectors that are the projections of w on the lines e1 = {y = x, z = 0}, e2 = {y = z, x = 0} and e3 = {z = x, y =0}.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection-matrices, projection

every one.The exercise also gives points A=(1,3,4) and B=(1,4,3) with a vector w=AB.
I found the w=(1-1,4-3,3-4)=(0,1,-1) and made a graph with the lines and w.

[image: graph]

After it asks me to find the projection vector matrices of P1,P2 and P3 but i guess thats easy after finding the vectors.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to find the P1,P2,P3 matrices without knowing the p1,p2,p3 vectors?

Comment: Certainly. Convert the equations of the lines into vector form.

Comment: So if i say p1=(1,0,1) p2=(0,1,1),p3=(1,1,0) and find the 3x3 projection matrices is right?